# hybris image in the WCMS

Tags: image, sap-commerce-cloud

Can someone please explain me what is the procedure of getting a picture to a product in the WCMS?

What am I missing?

I'm uploading the file, attaching media format to it, but as soon as go to the website and check the product there is no image but "image coming soon" ...

Comment: I m a bit of confusion about WCMS. Are you talking about Product Cockpit? Did you check in hmc whether media container attaching in your product? You might forgot to synchronize product catalog. To get product image on Listing page, it may require to re-index your solr facet also.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to be more specific about which image you're talking about, which image format, and where exactly it is that you're checking your product's image afterwards. Also which version of hybris you're using.

But there are a couple of things you could try:

- Make sure that the Product and the Medias have been synchronised to the online catalog;
- If it's an image from the galleryImages, make sure that the media container in the gallery has also been synchronised;
- You might also want to clear your hybris cache. Go to HAC - Monitoring - Cache - Clear Cache; Or clear other caches, such as JAWR or Varnish.

Comment: these are good suggestions but problem lies between keyboard and chair.

Comment: We are all bad when we're beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you mean WCMS and not the product cockpit?

Comment: I'm able to attach thumbnail and see it in the product cockpit, but when I check the product in the WCMS, even though it has an attached image, nothing is shown...